# Change netmask to increase number of IP addresses

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

On my LAN I have a dedicated server that runs the DNS/DHCP service using `dnsmasq`.

The assignable IP-range is set as: `dhcp-range=10.0.1.50,10.0.1.254,255.255.255.0,72h`

I want to increase the amount of IP-addresses. So, some time ago I tried changing the netmask thus: `dhcp-range=10.0.1.50,10.0.1.254,255.255.0.0,72h`

However, after that change all computers on the network seemed to have disappeared (not pingable). So, I changed back the netmask and everything started to work again.

Since then I've tried to find out what I might have done wrong or how I should have approached this. However, from what I gather, this should have worked and I can't figure out what I might have missed.

Any help is appreciated.

NB: I had not expected that a change of the netmask (without changing the IP-range itself) would cause problems. My next step would have been to stretch the IP range to `10.0.1.3,10.0.255.254`, but I never got that far. Not wanting to mess up the network I decided to ask here first.

Comment: All of your devices need to have the same subnet, including the internet router and the server dnsmasq runs on.

Comment: I thought the DNS would inform each device of the new mask when it renegotiated its lease

Comment: So you're saying I have to reboot all devices on the network after making the change to ensure that the netmask is communicated to them?

Comment: Don't forget the devices having a fixed ip

Comment: There's only one device with a fixed IP and that already has a mask of 255.255.0.0 ...

Comment: What do you mean with "lost connection"? "72h" means, your devices renew the leases after 72 hours or after reconnection/reboot. So devices having a new lease will not be able to communicate with the devices still running a 24bit subnet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59061/discussion-between-mausy5043-and-davidbaumann).